# Object of type NoneType has no length error

Tags: python, string, list, nonetype

I have written the following function to add the elements of a list to a string.

```
import random 
import string 

def printmatches (word,x):
    y = len(word)
    z = [" "] *y 
    i = 0 
    while i<y:
        if word[i] == x: 
            z[i] = x 
        else:
            z[i] = " "  
        i+=1

    return (z)

def append(string,chars): ##append list to a string
    q = 0
    while q < len(string): 
        if string[q] == " " and chars[q] != " ":
            string[q] = chars[q]
        q+=1  

x = random.randint(0,55899)

def convertlist(x):
    q = " "
    a = 0
    while (a < len(x)):
        q+=x[a]
        a+=1
    return (q) 

try:
    f = open('words.txt', 'r')
    s = " "
    s = f.readline()

    L = s.split()

    word = L[x]

    f.close()

except IOError:
    print('file not found')

q=0

print word

print (printmatches('ereesvox','o') == [" "] * 8)  
current = [" "] * len(word)  
c = 0
char = " " 
while char != word and q < 3 and c <35: 
    char = raw_input (" ") 
    c+=1
    ##current.append(printmatches(word,char)) 
    append(current, printmatches(word,char)) 
    str = (append(current, printmatches(word,char)))
    if (convertlist(str) == word): 
        print 'Congratulations, you have won'
    if printmatches(word,char) == [" "]*len(word):    
        print "You have ", (2-q), " guesses left"   
        q+=1 
    if (q == 3):
        print "Game over"
    print ' '.join(current)
```

x is meant to be a list but when I execute the code its type is interpreted as Nonetype, and I get the error message because I am trying to access elements within x and compare its length. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The error messages for the most part mean what they say. So if it's telling you that the var that you expect to be a list is `None`, then you should start looking for why `None` was passed in to your function. The interp doesn't get confused about what types it sees.  ;-) Maybe we could help more if you include some of the code taht invokes convertlist().

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post to include an example of the use of convertlist

Comment: a quick note - you're overriding the name of a built-in type with `str = "house"`. It'd be good to rename that var.

Comment: The code you've posted above works fine.. where's the code that's failing?

Comment: Which line does the error message say has the problem? Can you post the stack trace in a code box?

Comment: A file called "words.txt" containing some words was imported in the code file. The problem is caused by the line if (convertlist(str) == word): which attempts to compare a string to a word randomly chosen from "words.txt" Unlike when a string defined in the code file is compared to a list initialized in the code file, I get an error message

Comment: I think you should fundamentally change your approach to the problem. Start by giving things names that are longer than a single letter, and ideally using those names to indicate the purpose of those variables. There are multiple `x`s all over the program and I can't guess what any of them mean, nor can I discern the intended rules of the game being implemented here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def append(string,chars): ##append list to a string
    q = 0
    while q < len(string): 
        if string[q] == " " and chars[q] != " ":
            string[q] = chars[q]
        q+=1
```

This does not explicitly return a value, so it implicitly returns `None`.

(The name `string` is also a very poor choice here: first off, you expect to be passed a list rather than a string (since as you presumably learned earlier, you cannot modify a string like this), and second it hides the imported `string` module. But then again, your code does not *use* the `string` module, so you shouldn't `import` it in the first place.)

```
str = (append(current, printmatches(word,char)))
```

Now `str` is `None`, because it is the result of an `append` call.

```
if (convertlist(str) == word):
```

Now we attempt to `convertlist` with `None`, which of course does not work since we wanted a list to be passed in...

```
def convertlist(x):
    q = " "
    a = 0
    while (a < len(x)):
        q+=x[a]
        a+=1
    return (q)
```

... and thus here `len` is invalid applied to `None`.

---

The natural way to get information out of a function is to `return` that information. Create a new string in `append`, and `return` it; then you can use the result the way you're trying to use it. As a bonus, since you are creating a new object, you can actually pass in a string again.

Except, I have no idea why this function is called `append`, since despite the comment, it doesn't seem intended to do any such thing....

Answer (score -1):

Put a check before you perform any operation with x to see the x is not None or any other type than list.
Something like below,

```
def convertlist(x):
    q = " "
    a = 0
    if isinstance(x, list):
        while (a < len(x)):
            q+=x[a]
            a+=1
    return (q)
```

Comment: This is wrong-headed. It may succeed in getting the function to run without raising an exception, but it can only cause more logical errors down the line.